# Can someone recommend a niggunim / Jewish melodies book

Tags: music, books-generally, product-recommendation

I read notes well enough to sing them. I need two things:

1. Niggunim/Jewish melodies song book
2. Niggunim/Jewish melodies ADVANCED for piano

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look for anything by Velvel Pasternak. For example, The Jewish Fake Book or The Ultimate Jewish Piano Book (both on JewishMusic.com).

There are also more specialized collections, such as Sefer Hanigunim (2 vols.), a collection of Chabad niggunim.

Answer (score 2):

Another good reference, although scarce today, would be Abraham Baer's *בעל תפלה oder Der Praktische Vorbeter*.

Comment: Can be found at: http://www.nbn-resolving.de/urn:nbn:de:bvb:384-uba001658-2