# What book would be a good reference for prayer melodies?

Tags: product-recommendation, song-poetry, chazzan-prayer-leader, shabbat-songs, nusach-ashkenaz

When davening at different synagogues, I notice that some use different melodies for songs (eg: El Adon, Hallel, L'kha Dodi) as well as different nusach (in the sense of melodies for brachot used for the type of day it is) even among synagogues that all consider themselves Ashkenazim.  I assume that some of these differences are descended from differences that existed in Europe.  I am referring here to differences that seem to be intentional, not those from a shiliach tzibbur that cannot carry a tune or doesn't know the correct nusach for the service.  You can also hear these differences when a shatz that was raised in a different community leads a service.  When asking once such person, his response was "Well, you sing the melody that you learned as a kid, in my case in Chicago."

My question is, can anyone recommend a good book that lists or explains the different melodies that are used in different communities, ideally with sheet music.  For example, I would like to learn that xxx prayer was sung with this melody in Vilna, but this melody in Volhynia, and this melody in Frankfurt.

I would like to request some books like this on an interlibrary loan from a college or cantorial school.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Some of the books that I have found locally have arrangements by specific composers, sometimes for choirs, but that is not really what I want because (correct me if I am wrong) I do not think that represents what would have been heard historically in European synagogues.

Related: [can someone recommend a niggunim / jewish melodies book](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5522/can-someone-recommend-a-niggunim-jewish-melodies-book)

and

[Any good sources for Ashkenazi prayer modes and melodies for the whole year?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27037/any-good-sources-for-ashkenazi-prayer-modes-and-melodies-for-the-whole-year)

Comment: For Minhag Ashkenaz melodies, Baer's "Der Praktische Vorbeter" is a wonderful source. It also includes some Polish and Portuguese melodies.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt  Thanks!  Here it is online: http://www.nbn-resolving.de/urn:nbn:de:bvb:384-uba001658-2  or  http://bvbm1.bib-bvb.de/view/bvbmets/viewer.0.5.jsp?folder_id=0&dvs=1397098538337~281&pid=1976384&locale=en&usePid1=true&usePid2=true   This should keep me busy for a while!

Comment: Re "some use different melodies for songs (eg: El Adon, Hallel, L'kha Dodi)": this is very, very common in my experience. People use pretty much any song they like for these three songs, and I must have heard scores of different tunes to _Kel adon_. (This comment is *not* about _nusach_.)